# How can I add items and buttons as numbered list

Tags: javascript, html, button, textinput, numbered-list

This is my first project ever. I'm trying to make a simple to-do list for practice. One writes something, anything, on an input type text and it's supposed to show up below as a numbered list. Right next to the item in the list, there's supposed another button that eliminates the item.

How do I make it be a numbered list as I add items through the input text and how, at the same time, do I add input buttons along with the item?
How do I stop it from adding items when the input text is still empty?

My code so far:

HTML

```
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Add an item!" id="text1" class="text1" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="button1" />
  <input type="button" value="Clear List" id="button2" />
  <p id="write"></p>
</div>
```

JS

```js
var input2 = document.getElementById("button1");

input2.addEventListener("click", addStuff);

function addStuff() {
  todo = text1.value;
  add.innerHTML += todo + "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to create it on your own with the help of the following list. But if you get stuck you can use [ready-made code](https://codepen.io/SebastianZ/pen/xxdNOOv?editors=1010).

1. You have to add the `<ol>` tag to which notes will be added.
2. Add a method that removes content from a list using the `innerHTML` method.
3. Create a method that removes a single note. Inside using event object you can get a parent of a clicked button and remove it from the DOM using the `remove()` method.
4. Within the `addStuff` method, take the value of the text field. Then create a `button` and `li` with the `createElement` method, add the required attributes to each of them, and append `button` to `li` and `li` to the `ol` list.

#### Usefull links

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ordered list tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_ol.asp). it handles the numbered list by default, each item inside of it should be in a `<li>` tag.

in your `addStuff` function you'd need to 1. get the `ol` element, 2. append inside of it a new `li` for each item yo want.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code.

```js
var submitButton = document.getElementById("button1");
var clearButton = document.getElementById("button2");
var add = document.getElementById("write");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", addStuff);
clearButton.addEventListener("click", clear);

function addStuff()
{
    todo = text1.value;
    if(todo == "") {
        alert("Please input data");
    } else {
        add.innerHTML += "<li>" + todo + "</li>";
    }
}

function clear() {
    add.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add an item!" id="text1" class="text1">
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="button1">
        <input type="button" value="Clear List" id="button2">
        <ol id="write"></ol>
    </div>
```